# Using an Excel Range Name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use an existing workbook Range Name "value" in VBA.

I use cell E1 on a Config Tab that has been named "GridStartDate".
Looking at the Name Manager in Excel I see that the Value is 9/1/2022 and the "Refers to" is =Config!$E$1

I want to simply refer to the Sheet Name Range instead of the explicit cell

```
ShiftCells = DateDiff("d", Sheets("Config").Range("E1").Value, StartingDate)
```

With something like this:

```
ShiftCells = DateDiff("d", ActiveWorkbook.Names("GridStartDate").Value, StartingDate)
```

I'm concerned that if someone should add a column or row in the Config sheet it may move my GridStartField and therefor cause the above formula to fail.

I get a type mismatch when I use the revised codes because the Value is actually returning the refersto value it seems.  I find all sorts of information on adding Ranges with VBA but I don't understand how to use the value after the fact.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names("GridStartDate").RefersToRange.Value`

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank You so much AGAIN!  I'll do some "learning" now about what it actually means for me.  BUT it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You could read the [`Name.RefersToRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.referstorange) documentation perhaps.